# Animating onto, and keeping history for a tabbed page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm just starting out with Ionic, and have run into a bit of a confusing problem; I have a couple of pages set up (Properties, Test and Xyzzy) set up as follows in the router:

```
$stateProvider

    .state( 'properties', {
        url: '/properties',
        templateUrl: 'templates/properties.html',
        controller: 'PropertiesController'
    } )

    .state( 'test', {
        url: '/test',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/test.html',
        controller: 'TestController'
    } )
    .state( 'test.one', {
        url: '/one',
        views: {
            'one-tab': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/test-one.html',
                controller: 'TestController'
            }
        }
    } )
    .state( 'test.two', {
        url: '/two',
        views: {
            'two-tab': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/test-two.html',
                controller: 'TestController'
            }
        }
    } )

    .state( 'xyzzy', {
        url: '/xyzzy',
        templateUrl: 'templates/xyzzy.html',
        controller: 'XyzzyController'
    } );
```

Essentially there are two plain-and-simple pages (Properties and Xyzzy) and one page with tabs (Test). The templates for each page are very simple, and look like this - [Properties](http://puu.sh/kAkH0/7528de728f.png), [Xyzzy](http://puu.sh/kAkHI/1d9fa51adb.png) and [Test](http://puu.sh/kAkIw/c382f9492b.png)

Enough explaining, here's the problem: as you can see, the Xyzzy page has detected that I've navigated to it from the Properties page and gives me a nice back button. It doesn't show up if I go to the Test page though (with the tabs). The code for that is this:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Also, when I navigate between Properties and Xyzzy, the page slides left/right in a nice little animation which looks clean. However, when I go into the Test page, there's no transition at all, nor is there when I come out of it.

I've spent a couple of hours looking around Google but can't find anything relevant to transitions in/out of tabbed pages. Any ideas?

---

Update: Here's the code the views are being built off (in index.html):

```
<body ng-app="app">

<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the transition you can use

```
<ion-nav-view name="main" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
```

for your pages

Comment: I tried that and it looks like adding `name="main"` results in no content loading in, and adding `animated="slide-left-right"` changes no functionality - I've added my index.html to the first post, if that helps